# I want to be able to divide the column b w and g in the below table as shown in the image

Tags: columns

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
%\centering %% redundant
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ |l| *{5}{C|} }
\hline 
\textit{\textbf{Parameters}} & 
\textit{\textbf{Train (WOE)}} &
\textit{\textbf{Train (WRE)}} &
\textit{\textbf{G}} &
\textit{\textbf{B}} &
\textit{\textbf{W}}
\\ 
\hline
0.05\_0.025\_0.05\_0.2 & 42.72 & 44.89 & 677  & 76  & 497 \\ 
\hline
0.05\_0.05\_0.05\_0.1  & 48.55 & 55.19 & 440  & 67 & 569\\ 
\hline
0.05\_0.075\_0.05\_0.2 & 36.92 & 43.87 & 695 & 84 & 497\\ 
\hline
0.1\_0.05\_0.2\_0.2   & 38.09 & 53.03 & 436  & 112 & 486\\ 
\hline
0.2\_0.05\_0.05\_0     & 36.21 & 55.91 & 336 & 83 & 469\\ 
\hline
0.2\_0.05\_0.1\_0.05   & 43.12 & 60.67 & 243 & 127 & 447\\
\hline
Average & 40.93 & 52.26 & 471  & 87 & 495 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Comparison of Avg. fitness values without information exchange and with  information exchange by random approach}
\label{tab:Comparison of Avg. fitness values without information exchange and with  information exchange W.R.T random approach}   
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Columns can not be divided, you should insert new columns and merge cells, where you like to have one in place of two. In your case In column headers G, B, W. Please extend your code snippet to complete small but compilable document that people cane more easy to help you.

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure what would be the meaning of the thick rules.

Comment: i think he wants to split the G B H columns vertically / horizontally so that each column has two sub columns under it

Comment: Yes @ js bibra, i want to split g b and w equally

Answer (score 2):

You not provided any information, about width of new columns, so I guessing that you look for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ |l| *{2}{C|}*{3}{C|c|} }
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{\textbf{Parameters}}} 
    &   \textit{\textbf{Train}} 
        &   \textit{\textbf{Train}} 
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{G}}} 
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{B}}}
                            &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{W}}}    \\
    \cline{4-9}
    &   \textit{\textbf{(WOE)}}
        &   \textit{\textbf{(WRE)}}
            &   &   &   &   &   &                                           \\
    \hline
0.05\_0.025\_0.05\_0.2 & 42.72 & 44.89 & 677 & & 76 & & 497 &               \\
    \hline
0.05\_0.05\_0.05\_0.1  & 48.55 & 55.19 & 440 & & 67 & & 569 &               \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Comparison of Avg. fitness values without information exchange and with  information exchange by random approach}
\label{tab:Comparison of Avg. fitness values without information exchange and with  information exchange W.R.T random approach}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

or

[image]

for which you only need to change column headers:

```
...
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{\textbf{Parameters}}} 
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Train}}}
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{G}}} 
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{B}}}
                            &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{W}}}    \\
...
```

**Addendum:**
To have all columns (except the first) of the equal width, you need to specify this columns as `C` column type. Since by this table become quite wider, you need to reduce font size used in table and also reduce `\tabcolsep`. For better looking of table is advisable to increase `\arrraystreatch` table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \small  % <---
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}% <--- default is 6pt
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}% <---
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ |l| *{8}{C|}}
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{\textbf{Parameters}}}
    &   \textit{\textbf{Train}}
        &   \textit{\textbf{Train}}
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{G}}}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{B}}}
                            &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{W}}}    \\
    \cline{4-9}
    &   \textit{\textbf{(WOE)}}
        &   \textit{\textbf{(WRE)}}
            &   &   &   &   &   &                                           \\
    \hline
0.05\_0.025\_0.05\_0.2 & 42.72 & 44.89 & 677 & & 76 & & 497 &               \\
    \hline
0.05\_0.05\_0.05\_0.1  & 48.55 & 55.19 & 440 & & 67 & & 569 &               \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Comparison of Avg. fitness values without information exchange and with  information exchange by random approach}
\label{tab:Comparison of Avg. fitness values without information exchange and with  information exchange W.R.T random approach}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the G B and W must have sub-columns as you have added but they should be of equal width, the first one you have plotted looks perfect but i need it to be of equal width.

Comment: @MohammedNadeem, than you only need to replace `c` with `C`, or shortly `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ |l| *{8}{C|} }`.  See addendum to  answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the thick black rules are meant to show *alignment*.

For this you either manually pad the numeric entries to have three digits or use `siunitx`.

In this case it's not difficult to equalize the last five columns and to leave the surplus in the first column.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Comparison of Avg.\ fitness values without information exchange 
  and with  information exchange by random approach}
\label{tab:ComparisonAvgfitness}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
 |X|
 S[table-format=2.2] |
 S[table-format=2.2] |
 S[table-format=3.0] |
 S[table-format=3.0] |
 S[table-format=3.0] |
}
\hline 
\itshape\bfseries Parameters & 
{\itshape\bfseries Train} &
{\itshape\bfseries Train} &
{\itshape\bfseries G} &
{\itshape\bfseries B} &
{\itshape\bfseries W} \\
& 
{\itshape\bfseries (WOE)} &
{\itshape\bfseries (WRE)} & 
{\hphantom{11.11}} &
{\hphantom{11.11}} &
{\hphantom{11.11}} \\
\hline
0.05\_0.025\_0.05\_0.2 & 42.72 & 44.89 & 677  & 76  & 497 \\ 
\hline
0.05\_0.05\_0.05\_0.1  & 48.55 & 55.19 & 440  & 67 & 569\\ 
\hline
0.05\_0.075\_0.05\_0.2 & 36.92 & 43.87 & 695 & 84 & 497\\ 
\hline
0.1\_0.05\_0.2\_0.2   & 38.09 & 53.03 & 436  & 112 & 486\\ 
\hline
0.2\_0.05\_0.05\_0     & 36.21 & 55.91 & 336 & 83 & 469\\ 
\hline
0.2\_0.05\_0.1\_0.05   & 43.12 & 60.67 & 243 & 127 & 447\\
\hline
Average & 40.93 & 52.26 & 471  & 87 & 495 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the IEEE style (easily guessed from what you showed) wants table captions to sit above the table.

A different realization that you might find interesting.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\sisetup{detect-all}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Comparison of Avg.\ fitness values without information exchange 
  and with  information exchange by random approach}
\label{tab:ComparisonAvgfitness}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{
 @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
 l
 S[table-format=2.2]
 S[table-format=2.2]
 S[table-format=3.0]
 S[table-format=3.0]
 S[table-format=3.0]
 @{}
}
\toprule
\itshape\bfseries Parameters & 
{\itshape\bfseries Train} &
{\itshape\bfseries Train} &
{\itshape\bfseries G} &
{\itshape\bfseries B} &
{\itshape\bfseries W} \\
& 
{\itshape\bfseries (WOE)} &
{\itshape\bfseries (WRE)} \\
\midrule
0.05\_0.025\_0.05\_0.2 & 42.72 & 44.89 & 677  & 76  & 497 \\ 
0.05\_0.05\_0.05\_0.1  & 48.55 & 55.19 & 440  & 67 & 569\\ 
0.05\_0.075\_0.05\_0.2 & 36.92 & 43.87 & 695 & 84 & 497\\ 
0.1\_0.05\_0.2\_0.2   & 38.09 & 53.03 & 436  & 112 & 486\\ 
0.2\_0.05\_0.05\_0     & 36.21 & 55.91 & 336 & 83 & 469\\ 
0.2\_0.05\_0.1\_0.05   & 43.12 & 60.67 & 243 & 127 & 447\\
\midrule
Average & 40.93 & 52.26 & 471  & 87 & 495 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]